# Unable to access file (url_private property) when file was uploaded by slackbot

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm trying to upload a file using slackbot and then posting it as a url_private link in my channel. Then when I click on the url_private link the browser throws the error:

```
The page isn’t redirecting properly An error occurred during a connection to xxx.slack.com. This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

My code:

```
client = WebClient(token=os.environ.get("SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"))
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

try:
    result = client.files_upload(
        initial_comment="Here's my file :smile:",
        file=file_name,
    )
    logger.info(result)
    os.environ['PRIVATE_URL'] = result["file"]["url_private"]

except SlackApiError as e:
    logger.error("Error uploading file: {}".format(e))

def post_message_to_slack(blocks = None):
    return requests.post('https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage', {
        'token': os.environ['USER_TOKEN'],
        'channel': "#test",
        'as_user': 'username',
        'blocks': json.dumps(blocks)
    }).json()

print(post_message_to_slack(blocks))
```

This is how I receive result:
[image]

The SLACK_BOT_TOKEN and USER_TOKEN has files:write, files:read permissions.

I don't know why I'm not able to access the file after I login to my slack account.